# Could we clarify that comments entered when not interested in a Careers message will still be sent to the sender?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, spam, private-messaging

I received a private message from a company for something I was absolutely uninterested in.  I actually was set to allow communications when I shouldn't have been, so this was partially my fault, but the message was spam.  I was given an option to choose if I was interested, and it seemed to indicate that saying I was interested would send a message back to the person.

So I chose that I was not interested, and a comments box appeared.  So in the comments box, I typed:

"This looks like it was a spam message sent out to a large number of users in hopes of finding a needle in a haystack. I do not appreciate receiving job offers in San Francisco when I am not located there."

This message was then sent to the employer, who responded today with a nasty message telling me to RTFM:

"Your assumptions of spammy malice are mutually unappreciated. One of the thinks that makes Careers 2.0 so great is that employers cannot send out large volumes of messages mindlessly ... If you want more targeted messages from other employers, go RTFM, set the geographic preferences, and fill out your profile with more detail."

I replied with this:

"That message was not intended for you. I chose *NOT* to reply, and filled in that text as feedback. I'm sorry that it was sent to you."

I would hope that we could clarify in the interface that even though you are choosing that you are NOT interested, any comments entered will be sent to the employer, and not just used by careers.SO as feedback, which is what I assumed.

Comment: Are you talking about Careers? If so, please tag properly.

Comment: I wasn't entirely aware that I was in meta.SE.  I'm trying to be helpful and give feedback, but I'm also trying to get work done.  I thought it was a meta.careers site.  Sorry.

Comment: Fair enough. Anyway back to the topic, you chose that you're not interested in the job offer, not that don't want to reply. You actually reply to the message saying "Not interested", with optional comments. So maybe adding a preview would help?

Comment: I would be happy with a radio button saying "send comments as: ( ) Response to Sender  ( ) Careers.SE Staff"

Comment: There is no way to send messages to the staff from within Careers site itself as far as I can tell. You can email them, or use this very site to report things or interact with the Careers team. So such radio button isn't likely to happen.

Comment: Ouch, that's unfortunate. Making it possible to submit feedback to the Careers' staff may not happen yet, but we can make it obvious that your response goes to the employer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have several ways to report messaging spam. You can e-mail careers@stackoverflow.com, post on meta.se, or even ping our Twitter account @StackCareers.

As far as the spam, I really don't see the message as spam. They are offering relocation for the position so the location in this matter doesn't factor in to their decision to contact you. In addition, you are a highly ranked SO user in SO tags that are complementary to the position.

That said, the customer probably shouldn't have been so confrontational. I'll be happy to talk to them to avoid future issues.

Adding a company feedback mechanism for messages is on the books but as always we have a larger workload than our dev team can handle at the moment.

**EDIT** - Someone pointed out that I may have read that incorrectly. We'll be making a small change to the wording so that it's clear the response will go to the messenger and not us.

Comment: Why did you tag this completed? Did you change anything in the UI?

Comment: Sorry. Butter fingers. I've changed the tag.

Comment: Cheers, I also noticed it's not tagged as feature request while it is, solved this one myself. :-)

Comment: Thanks, this sounds good to me.