# Has any [status-deferred] issue ever been completed?

Tags: discussion

While browsing questions on Meta SE, I found [the following comment by Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257277/area-51-on-ios-app#comment839102_257277).

> I'm here for ~5 years, never seen even a single status-deferred
>   becoming status-completed. By all means, it's just a different wording
>   for status-rejected.

Is this true? Has an issue tagged [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) ever been recategorized as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

Comment: I have an experience, from `status-declined` to `status-deferred` in this [MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/328091/revisions). It means instead `status-declined` they used `status-deferred` in most of the cases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

The most obvious example is [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites), which was [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) on [2011-12-21](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/116782/3). It became [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) on [2013-06-27](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/116782/4) and was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) on [2017-05-22](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/116782/8) when [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) reached near completion.

More generally, it's possible to construct a query using the Data Explorer to [find them](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/664337/subsequently-completed-status-deferred-posts). There are 67 questions in total which have been completed after being deferred.

The most recently deferred post that has been completed is [Security hole: password change dialog doesn't ask for a user's current password](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232256/security-hole-password-change-dialog-doesnt-ask-for-a-users-current-password), which was deferred in March 2016 and completed in October of the same year.

We can also change the query to give us [the times between deferral and completion](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/664332/max-time-between-subsequently-completed-status-deferred-posts). The maximum time is almost 5 years (1,765 days) to complete [Allow users to set the "base" profile that your stackexchange.com profile inherits from](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81750/allow-users-to-set-the-base-profile-that-your-stackexchange-com-profile-inheri). The least are [Could we clarify that comments entered when not interested in a Careers message will still be sent to the sender?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234143/could-we-clarify-that-comments-entered-when-not-interested-in-a-careers-message) and [Profile-hover-quick-view thingy isn't loading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208865/profile-hover-quick-view-thingy-isnt-loading), which were deferred and completed on the same day... probably doesn't actually count as a deferral...

Comment: Doggone it, I was writing [my own query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/664338/questions-that-have-ever-contained-this-tag) to scoop you! Well played.

Comment: Sorry @Nathan! I accidentally posted the first version before I'd started writing the queries so I had to go and finish them...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Your query is correct, it finds all, not most. If the body and tags are edited at the same time it ends up with two separate PostHistory entries: One for the tags, and one for the body. They'll have the same RevisionGUID but will be separate entries. Btw, your query can be [simplified](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/666322).